# Overriding Remote Repository in Premake5 script running

Tags: c++, nuget, nuget-package, premake, manage-nuget-packages

I have a C++ project on Visual Studio 2022 that when trying to setup, I'm unable of running the premake5 script with vs2022 parameter on cmd.

I have a custom package that resides in my local system.
when Running the premake5, it searches for the remote packages in https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json and it's failing because my package does not exist there.
Therefore, I'm asking what the is way/syntax to override in premake5.lua the remote repository or to make the script to search for packages in my local system also for example ( C:/NuGetPackages ) .

```
C:\Users>./premake5.exe vs2022
Found Sysroot of /
Building configurations...
Running action 'vs2022'...
Examining NuGet package source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'...
Examining NuGet package 'Project.Custom'...
Error: ** Error: NuGet package 'Project.Custom' for project 'Project' couldn't be found in the repository
```

Tried to search the documentation of premake, didn't find how to get that.
What i'm looking for is to make the script also search for packages in my custom directory (locally)

Comment: Have you tried [`nugetsource`](https://premake.github.io/docs/nugetsource)?

Comment: Update how I solved the issue, it looks like that premake5 tries to get from local cache first if the packages are found there. So I copied my missing packages to the Nuget cache folder and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update how I solved the issue, it looks like that premake5 tries to get from local cache first if the packages are found there. So I copied my missing packages to the Nuget cache folder and that fixed the issue.

Comment: It seems more a hack than the actual fix. You should provide other source with `nugetsource` (including local directory normally).